# tf.print not printing the prints in the console

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following loss function that contains tf.print statements:

```
@tf.function
def loss(i, o):
  tf.print("i shape is ")
  tf.print(i.shape)
  tf.print("o shape is ")
  tf.print(o.shape)
  loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.abs(i - o))
  tf.print("loss is ")
  tf.print(loss)
  tf.print(loss)
  return loss
```

And loss is called as follows in the training step:

```
l_loss = loss(l_output, x_train_left_noc)
```

However, there aren't any prints in the console. How to see the prints?

Comment: Apparently, the output stream isn't standard out - have you tried adding the `output_stream=sys.stdout` parameter?

Comment: doesn't print with sys.stout either

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

tensor = tf.range(10)
tf.print(tensor, output_stream=sys.stderr)
```

I am using tensorflow 2.x
Specify **output_stream=sys.stderr**

Comment: Can plz you accept and upvote if the solution worked.